# Stripes ActionBean event always resolve to default event

Tags: java, stripes

I am using cleanurls formatted like  `/View/{arg1}/{arg2}/{$event}`.

`ActionBeanView` has multiple events. However irrespective of which event I invoke from browser, this always gets resolved to the default event.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong (fairly new to Stripes).

Here is the error log:

```
11:24:18,497 DEBUG UrlBindingFactory:145 - Matched /View/myarg1/myarg2/ADD.action to [/View/{id}/{asof}/{$event}]

11:24:18,497 DEBUG ExecutionContext:150 - Transitioning to lifecycle stage Reque
stInit

11:24:18,497 DEBUG ExecutionContext:150 - Transitioning to lifecycle stage Actio
nBeanResolution

11:24:18,497 DEBUG UrlBindingFactory:145 - Matched /View/myarg1/myarg2/ADD.action to [/View/{id}/{asof}/{$event}]

11:24:18,497 DEBUG UrlBindingFactory:145 - Matched /View/myarg1/myarg2/ADD.action to [/View/{id}/{asof}/{$event}]

11:24:18,497 DEBUG ExecutionContext:150 - Transitioning to lifecycle stage Handl
erResolution

11:24:18,497 DEBUG UrlBindingFactory:145 - Matched /View/myarg1/myarg2/ADD.action to [/View/{id}/{asof}/{$event}]

11:24:18,497 DEBUG DispatcherHelper:184 - Resolved event: myDefaultEvent; will invoke:
 ViewActionBean.myDefaultEvent()

11:24:18,497 DEBUG ExecutionContext:150 - Transitioning to lifecycle stage Bindi
ngAndValidation

11:24:18,497 DEBUG DefaultActionBeanPropertyBinder:453 - Running required field
validation on bean class www.ViewActionBean

11:24:18,497 DEBUG DefaultActionBeanPropertyBinder:779 - Converting 1 value(s) u
sing converter net.sourceforge.stripes.validation.StringTypeConverter

11:24:18,513 DEBUG DefaultActionBeanPropertyBinder:779 - Converting 1 value(s) u
sing converter net.sourceforge.stripes.validation.StringTypeConverter

11:24:18,513 DEBUG DefaultActionBeanPropertyBinder:282 - Could not bind property
 with name [ADD.action] to bean of type: ViewActionBean : Bean class www.View
ActionBean does not contain a property called 'ADD'. As a result the followin
g expression could not be evaluated: ADD.action
----
```

Comment: Rather weird url.  Shouldn't the url be View/myarg1/myarg2/add instead of View/myarg1/myarg2/ADD.action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to match an URL like: `/View/myarg1/myarg2/ADD.action` with an [UrlBinding](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/UrlBinding.html) `/View/{arg1}/{arg2}/{$event}` then I would expect Stripes to resolve this to the event named: "ADD.action".

As you did not provide any source code of the Action Bean, I suspect that you didn't annotated the event handler with an [HandlesEvent](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Annotation+Reference#AnnotationReference-@HandlesEvent) like this:

```
@HandlesEvent("ADD.action")
public Resolution add() {
   ... do handle add ...
}
```